# How can I get my raspberry pi 3 to work with SK6812 LEDs without a screen?

Tags: gpio, pi-3, led

I have a raspberry pi 3 and am trying to get it to run the SK6812 LEDs with no screen. When I have my ASUS monitor connected, the LEDs work fine, and when I disconnect the screen and reboot, the LEDs freak out and don't work.

I'm using "NeoPixels on Raspberry Pi" by Adafruit (https://learn.adafruit.com/neopixels-on-raspberry-pi) as a guide. I'm also using the SK6812_strandtest.py example included in their library.

Comment: How are you executing the python script when it works properly?

Comment: I run "sudo python SK6812_strandtest.py".

Comment: When you reboot with the screen disconnected, how are you executing the python script?

Comment: "sudo python SK6812_strandtest.py" I use SSH with or without the display.

Comment: What happens if you plug the monitor in when the LEDs are malfunctioning? FYI, I was exploring if this was an issue with trying to have the python script start automatically. Now I'm curious if this is power related. Perhaps the monitor is pulling the supply voltage down just a little bit but enough to meet the LED requirements.

Comment: The LEDs continue to malfunction.  It still malfunctions if I restart X. They will only work if I reboot the pi with the ASUS connected. I am also using an Arduino Uno as a power supply(so the pi's voltage does not drop).

Comment: It sounds suspiciously like it's a grounding issue. I recently had a similar thing where my scope output was great when I had a monitor plugged in, but was garbage when I unplugged the monitor. Is the Uno ground tied to the RPi ground?